# spoon pentaho spanish month format to convert string to date

Tags: date, format, pentaho-spoon

I have following dates format in spanish "Marzo 2023" with means March 2023.

I am using spoon to create an ETL to get dates like "Enero 2023", "Marzo 2023", etc to 01/2023, 03/2023 date format.

[image: Select and update field]

But it does not work since I have Month in spanish. Any idea to specify languaje or similar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a way to specify the full name of month format in the *Select Values* step, what you are trying to use in your screenshot is a format that it's not recognized in that step, you can use that in the *Modified JavaScript value* step where you are coding a script using JavaScript.

What I would do instead would be to separate your delivery_DATE field into two fields, month and year, then I would add a *Data Grid* step to hardcode the equivalence between month name and month number, *merge join* those two streams of data (remember to sort both streams by the name of the month before merging) and then join again month number and year and transform it to a date value.

Or, if you don't have much data (the *Modified JavaScript value* step can be slow with a lot of data) and are comfortable with coding, you can perform all that in JavaScript.